# "No suitable driver found " error is displayed while trying to connect to Sybase using Dbeaver DB

Tags: java, database-connection, web-api-testing

"No suitable driver found " error is displayed while trying to connect to Sybase using Dbeaver DB.I am using jconnect4.jar file to set the jdbc driver with below command:

```
Class.forName("com.sybase.jdc4.jdbc.SybDriver")
```

and trying to connect to database using below code

```
Driver Manager.get connection("jdbc:Sybase:TDs://hostname:port name/sunane","username","passed")
```

Please let me know what is wrong in my method.

Comment: why is this tagged selenium?

Comment: Because I am trying to connect to db to execute a query in my selenium project. So, I thought people who are doing selenium might have come across such scenarios. By the way I have figured out the issue and now it's working fine .